# windows server run nodejs app on port 80

Tags: asp.net, node.js, iis, hosting, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having a windows server which has already a asp.net application hosted and also several websites using IIS.Now i have to host a nodejs application on a domain.But i cant run this app on port 80.it showing following error.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\Administrator>cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app

    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app>node server.js
    (node) util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
    Http Server running at http://serverip:80/
    events.js:141
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: listen EACCES serverip:80
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:849:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:872:20)
        at Server._listen2 (net.js:1218:19)
        at listen (net.js:1267:10)
        at net.js:1376:9
        at doNTCallback3 (node.js:441:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:347:17)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:477:11)
        at startup (node.js:118:18)
        at node.js:952:3

    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app>node server.js
    (node) util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
    Http Server running at http:/serverip:80/
    events.js:141
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: listen EACCES serverip:80
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:849:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:872:20)
        at Server._listen2 (net.js:1218:19)
        at listen (net.js:1267:10)
        at net.js:1376:9
        at doNTCallback3 (node.js:441:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:347:17)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:477:11)
        at startup (node.js:118:18)
        at node.js:952:3

    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app>

    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app>
```

On research i came to know that IIS is using port 80.Is there any way to host the app on port 80 along with other asp.net applications?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your answer: For TCP, NO. You can only have one application listening on a single port at one time.
Now if you have 2 network cards, you can have one application listen on the first IP and run second application on second IP using the same port number.

For UDP (Multicasts), multiple applications can subscribe to the same port.

Comment: you are telling that there is no way to host on port 80. i have to switch the server.right?

Comment: if am running on any other port can i access the app using "www.domainname.com" url instead on "www.domainname.com:port"?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to my question after a long term research.This may be helpful for someone looking  for solution for the same problem.

Finally i came to know iisnode module and i have hosted an app on production using iisnode.It is working cool.Only thing you need to do is intall the module and follow their instructions.

https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html

As described in the above url,says it got cool features while doing so.